# Changing an Indesign Swatch incrementally with Extendscript (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have an InDesign doc with the swatch named *"mySwatch"* which is `C10 M20 Y30 K40`. I have written the line:

```js
app.activeDocument.colors.item("mySwatch").colorValue = [9,19,30,41];
```

to change it to a specific set of values (`9,19,30,41`), but I would like to instead add or subtract from the existing values, let's say [`-1`, `-1`, `unchanged`, `+1`].

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to get the values out by assigning them to a new variable.

```
var myvalues = app.activeDocument.colors.item("mySwatch").colorValue
```

Do your operations on them.

```
myvalues[0] = myvalues[0] - 1
```

Reassign them to your swatch.

```
app.activeDocument.colors.item("mySwatch").colorValue = myvalues
```

*(Not tested)*

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_color(a, b) {
    return [a[0] += b[0], a[1] += b[1], a[2] += b[2], a[3] += b[3]];
}

var color  = app.activeDocument.colors.item("mySwatch").colorValue; // [10,20,30,40]
var change = [-1, -1,  0,  1];
app.activeDocument.colors.item("mySwatch").colorValue = change_color(color, change); // [9,19,30,41];
```

Tested.